# reader.readLine() only reading first line of txt document

Tags: c#, readline

I am having trouble getting my console to output all the lines in my `students.txt` file, currently I'm only getting one single student details (student details are one student per line). Here is most of the code I currently have written.

This is the class I use to read each line and store the line broken down into a list.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Test
{
    class QA
    {
        public List<Student> students;

        public QA()
        {
            students = new List<Student>();
            string line;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("/Users/jvb/Desktop/Test/Test/Students.txt"))
            {
                    line = reader.ReadLine();
                    var s = line.Split(',');
                    int id = int.Parse(s[0]);
                    int houseNo = int.Parse(s[3]);
                    var status = int.Parse(s[7]);
                    Student sData = new Student(id, s[1], s[2], houseNo, s[4], s[5], s[6], (StudentStatus)status);
                    AddStudent(sData);
            }
        }


        public List<Student> GetStudents()
        {
            return students;
        }

        public void AddStudent(Student student)
        {
            students.Add(student);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the program.cs file I use to output everything to the user,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            QA qa = new QA();

            foreach (var s in qa.GetStudents())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should be using `File.ReadAllLines` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well as the method name imples, it reads a line, starting from first line, to read the other lines you should repeat it:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("/Users/jvb/Desktop/Test/Test/Students.txt"))
{
     while(!reader.EndOfStream)
     {             
          line = reader.ReadLine();
          var s = line.Split(',');
          int id = int.Parse(s[0]);
          int houseNo = int.Parse(s[3]);
          var status = int.Parse(s[7]);
          Student sData = new Student(id, s[1], s[2], houseNo, s[4], s[5], s[6], (StudentStatus)status);
          AddStudent(sData);
     }
}
```

Or as @CamiloTerevinto said, to read all lines you may try

```
File.ReadAllLines()
```

That is also what I always use, it short, simple, efficient

Comment: Ah, of course, silly me. I was under the assumption the readline function operated until it was null on its own. Many thanks!

Comment: @JayVB you are very welcome. we all make these kind of mistakes.

Comment: May I also ask one small question? How does the readLine() function know it's currently at the `nth` line in the text file, i.e. how does it know not to just read the first line over and over again?

Comment: @JayVB I looked into the source code, this is a comment in its source code: > `// Reads a line. A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by
        // a carriage return ('\r'), a line feed ('\n'), or a carriage return
        // immediately followed by a line feed. The resulting string does not
        // contain the terminating carriage return and/or line feed. The returned
        // value is null if the end of the input stream has been reached.`

Comment: you can study the source code here: [https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example from the Microsoft docs for [StreamReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Test 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        try 
        {
            // Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file.
            // The using statement also closes the StreamReader.
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt")) 
            {
                string line;
                // Read and display lines from the file until the end of 
                // the file is reached.
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            // Let the user know what went wrong.
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the while loop inside the using block. Your code should also have a similar while loop to read al lines in your file